# WSO2 exclude property from log

Tags: wso2, esb, wso2-esb

I am new to wso2 and I want to log all the properties in the incoming request except one property
here's my code:

```
<log level="full"/>
    <propertyGroup>
        <property expression="json-eval($.username)" name="Username" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
        <property expression="json-eval($.password)" name="Password" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
        <property expression="json-eval($.objectStore)" name="ObjectStore" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
        <property expression="json-eval($.documentClass)" name="DocumentClass" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
        <property expression="json-eval($.fileName)" name="FileName" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
        <property expression="json-eval($.fileData)" name="FileData" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
        <property expression="json-eval($.contentType)" name="ContentType" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
    </propertyGroup>
```

I want to exclude the fileData property from log because it's base64

is there's any solution other than a custom log that has only the properties that I want to log ?

Answer (score 2):

Its not posible by default i think. You can write your custom mediator for logging necessary attributes and properties

Answer (score 0):

By default, the `<log level="full"/>` won't log your property - it is logging standard headers (i.e. To, From, WSAction, SOAPAction, ReplyTo, and MessageID) and the **full payload** of the message. And as i see in your example - `json-eval($.fileData)` is part of the JSON payload.

So, there is no other option than using a custom logger.